# Conectar banco de dados do meu pc na hospedagem

Tags: php, mysql, sql, apache, sql-update

Quero conectar a hospedagem no banco de dados local do meu PC
Estou usando Linux. Tenho as portas `1604` e `8080` aberta. Quando eu acesso meu `ip:porta` em uma rede externa, consigo acessar meu site. Mas quando vou acessar a hospedagem, não conecta no banco de dados local.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('200.22X.XXX.XXX', 'exemploUser', 'exemploPass', 'banco','8080');
```

Comment: Amigo, porta 8080 é usada pra http. Os bancos se for mysql geralmente fica na porta 3306, ou uma maior. Melhor vc descobrir qual porta seu banco está escutando.

Comment: Acontece q n tenho a porta 3306 aberta na minha rede, eu coloquei a 1604 no mysql e 8080 no apache

Comment: Então você deve conectar na 1604, não consegue conectar por essa porta? dá algum erro?

Comment: Já consegui conectar